# Is there a way to make Git change its ncat command in `git push`?

Tags: windows, git, push

Upon running this command: `$ git push origin DC_PLATFORMAPP-1571`

I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\ncat.exe: illegal option -- X
Ncat: Try `--help' or man(1) ncat for more information, usage options and help. QUITTING.
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

This has only been happening since installing nmap for windows from here: https://nmap.org/download.html

Is there a way to make git change it's ncat command built into `git push`?

The error occurs in Git bash. On windows CMD, this error occurs:

```
error: src refspec DC_PLATFORMAPP-1517 does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
error: src refspec DC_PLATFORMAPP-1517 does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
```

Comment: Your OS is Windows ; are you running your command from `git-bash` ? from `cmd.exe` ? from powershell ? or from bash on WSL ?

Comment: This error appears on git bash. On windows CMD, something else happens:
```
git push origin DC_PLATFORMAPP-1517
error: src refspec DC_PLATFORMAPP-1517 does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
error: src refspec DC_PLATFORMAPP-1517 does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
```